# How to define a clip path that doesn't scale with image

Tags: html, svg, clip-path

I'm trying to shape a polygon over some images i have in my website.
My problem is that the polygon isn't always the same width and its based on the image width. 
I've created a codepen which you can see my problem:
http://codepen.io/doronsever/pen/bdyqYq .

Here is the code that generates my svg clipath

```
<svg class="clip-svg" width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip-shape" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" >
      <polygon points=".04,1, .04 .04, 0 0, 1 0, 1 1" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

As you can see, the small triangle on the upper left isn't the same size on both images.
How can i control it so it will always be on the same size regardless of the image width?
I cannot use css clip path since i need FF support...
10x

Comment: Use different SVGs for different sized images. Rationale: the entire SVG gets scaled, and you cannot scale *some* points and others not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do it that way, because as you have discovered, the clip path stretches with the image it is applied to.

You need to use a `clipPath` that is defined with `clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse"`. So it is of constant size and doesn't scale with the image.

```css
.clip-svg-inline {
    -webkit-clip-path: url("#clip-polygon");
    clip-path: url("#clip-polygon");
    position: relative;                  /* Makes clip relative to image position instead of page */
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);  /* Workaround for bug in Chrome */
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNWAN.jpg" class="clip-svg-inline" width="300px" >
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbwo2.jpg" class="clip-svg-inline">

<svg class="clip-svg">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip-polygon" clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
      <polygon points="2000 0, 2000 2000, 12 2000, 12 12, 0 0" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: 10x!, exactly what i needed

Comment: @Paul Lebau, I am facing the same issue. I didn't want my SVG to stretch, which I have working now thanks to your answer! However, would you know how I can keep the SVG centered on my image? ( I am trying to cut out a triangle at the top of an image)

Comment: @Arjenovic Create a question with an explanation of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Okay, done! :) Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42567313/how-to-center-a-clipping-svg-over-an-image-while-keeping-its-aspect-ratio